# Flink Elasticsearch connector 7 with SSL

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my flink job, I am trying to use **elasticsearch7** connector. I could not find a way to communicate over SSL when using **Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder** Am I missing something?

Also there is an deprecated class **ElasticsearchSink.Builder** where it has **RestClientFactory** which I can use to setup https connection but since this class is deprecated thus wondering if same is possible with **Elasticsearch7SinkBuilder**.

Also since there is no connector for **elasticsearch 8** yet, Is it possible to use any of the above client with elastic 8?

Note: Earlier it used to be elastic connector compatibility matrix in Flink doc but I could not find it any more in lasted version of doc.

Answer (score 0):

SSL connections to Elasticsearch7 are currently not supported and are tracked under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-27054

An Elasticsearch8 connector is being tracked under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26088. You can't use the ES7 connector to connect to an ES8 cluster.